# How to calculate distance between 2 elements , Like this?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

How to calculate distance between 2 elements , Like this ?

i want to calculate distance between `id="element_bottom"` and `id="ref_box"`

and this is fiddle for calculate distance between `mouse` and `id="element_bottom"`

how can i apply this code for calculate distance between `id="element_bottom"` and `id="ref_box"` ?

thankyou

http://jsfiddle.net/t5Kts/808/

```
(function() {

    var mY, distance_bottom,
        $distance_bottom = $('#distance_bottom span'),
        $element_bottom  = $('#element_bottom');            

    function calculatedistance_bottom(elem , mouseY) {
        return Math.floor(Math.sqrt(Math.pow(mouseY - (elem.offset().top+(elem.height()/2)), 2)));
    }

    $(document).mousemove(function(e) {        
        mY = e.pageY;
        distance_bottom = calculatedistance_bottom($element_bottom , mY);
        $distance_bottom.text(distance_bottom);         
    });
})();
```

Comment: here: http://jsfiddle.net/t5Kts/809/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the your references for distance are the tops of each element, You may try this:

[***DEMO***](http://jsfiddle.net/t5Kts/812/)

```
(function() {
    var btm = $('#element_bottom'),
        ref = $('#ref_box'),
        refTop = ref.position().top;


    $(window).scroll(function(){
       var btmTop = btm.position().top;
        $('#distance_bottom span').text(Math.abs(refTop-btmTop));

    });    

})();
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should probably do it:

```
$('.foo').offset().top - $('.bar').offset().top
```